# Can I deduct a contribution to an IRA if I also contribute to a 401(k) in the same tax year?

Tags: united-states, 401k, tax-deduction, ira, contribution

Can I deduct a contribution to a traditional IRA if I am also contributing to a 401(k) in the same tax year?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are *eligible* to participate in an employer-provided retirement plan like a 401(k), your right to deduct an IRA contribution is phased out once your income reaches a certain level. Note this is true even if you choose not to participate.

This is from the IRS website for 2010:

*"If either you or your spouse was covered by an employer retirement plan, you may be entitled to only a partial (reduced) deduction or no deduction at all, depending on your income and your filing status.
  Your deduction begins to decrease (phase out) when your income rises above a certain amount and is eliminated altogether when it reaches a higher amount. These amounts vary depending on your filing status."*

Here is the link:
https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-publication-590-a

Comment: It doesn't matter whether or not you participate in the 401(k) plan, all that matters is that you were "covered", i.e. eligible to participate.

Comment: @DanTilkin good eye, I didn't catch that part.