# Can I contribute deductible money to a traditional IRA if I left my job before maxing out my 401(k) for the year?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, irs

I've read these answers:

- [Can I deduct a contribution to an IRA if I also contribute to a 401(k) in the same tax year?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/9649/can-i-deduct-a-contribution-to-an-ira-if-i-also-contribute-to-a-401k-in-the-sa)
- [401K participant for part of year - Can I contribute to an IRA?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/29067/401k-participant-for-part-of-year-can-i-contribute-to-an-ira)
- [Can I contribute money to a 401k, 457b, and an IRA all at the same time?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/38982/can-i-contribute-money-to-a-401k-457b-and-an-ira-all-at-the-same-time)

but some of them are pretty old, some of the links are dead, and I'm not sure if any applies exactly to my situation.

My former employer offers a 401(k) plan, to which I had contributed about 60% of the annual limit when I left that job around 60% of the way through the year.

For the remaining 40% of the year I am/will not be covered by any retirement plan.  Can I contribute any deductible money to my traditional IRA?

The IRS website has [a page for folks covered by a retirement plan at work](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/plan-participant-employee/2018-ira-contribution-and-deduction-limits-effect-of-modified-agi-on-deductible-contributions-if-you-are-covered-by-a-retirement-plan-at-work) and [a page for those who are not](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/plan-participant-employee/2018-ira-contribution-and-deduction-limits-effect-of-modified-agi-on-deductible-contributions-if-you-are-not-covered-by-a-retirement-plan-at-work), but no page for a person in both categories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe [this article](https://www.irs.gov/retirement-plans/are-you-covered-by-an-employers-retirement-plan) answers the question:

> ## Are You Covered by an Employer's Retirement Plan?
>
> You’re covered by an employer retirement plan for a tax year if your employer (or your spouse’s employer) has a:
>
> - Defined contribution plan (profit-sharing, 401(k), stock bonus and money purchase pension plan) and any contributions or forfeitures were allocated to your account for the plan year ending with **or within the tax year**;

So being covered by a plan at any part of the year is sufficient.

Comment: Ok, that updated content certainly answers my question.